# AlarmManager doesn't trigger to my service

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager, utc

I set my AlarmManager like below:

```
Intent startIntent =  new Intent(context, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, startIntent, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000, pendingIntent);
Log.d(TAG, "Current time is " + System.currentTimeMillis());
Log.d(TAG, "Next alarm time is: " + (alarmManager.getNextAlarmClock().getTriggerTime() - System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

It shows

 Current time is 1499909678520

 Next alarm time is: 55521479

I thought RTC is UTC time using the System.currentTimeMillis(). Should next alarm be a number less than 3000?

FYI, in my service, I handle it like this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  Log.i(TAG, "MyService started");
}
```

My service never starts. What's going wrong?

Comment: `getNetAlarmClock()` returns the next alarm clock scheduled. I cant tell from the code you posted if you have scheduled any(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#getNextAlarmClock()).

`alarmManager.set()` creates an intent broadcast. You will need a broadcast receiver to receive the pending intent and act on it( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)). Note the line **The alarm is an Intent broadcast that goes to a broadcast receiver that you registered**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a stupid mistake in showing logs. So, my code actually works. But, I guess alarmManager.getNextAlarmClock().getTriggerTime() doesn't return in UTC which causing the difference to System.currentTimeMills().

Answer (score 1):

**For repeating alarm use:**

```
// Alarm time :: Current time
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance() ;
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

// Interval
long interval = 3000; // 3 seconds

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

**Instead of:**

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000, pendingIntent);
```

Make sure you have declared `MyService` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: My service is declared with android:exported="false". I want to set an oneoff alarm, not repeating one.

Comment: Ohh... For single alarm I think your code seems fine